# How to create dynamic filter in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
data = {key:0, Name:"Arun", key:1, Name:"Ajay", key:3, Name:"Ashok"}

function dynamicfilter(data, fieldName, filtervalue){
    $filter('filter')(data, { fieldName: filtervalue });
}
```

How to do the dynamic filter in AngularJS. I tried like this it's not working.

But If I give field name static like

```
 function dynamicfilter(data, filtervalue){
        $filter('filter')(data, { Key: filtervalue });
    }
```

It's working. May I know how set dynamic field filter inside controller in AngularJS?

Comment: Typo there: `Key` in `dynamicfilter()` should be `key`, all lowercase.

Comment: I think what Suresh is asking is how to pass in a property name to dynamically filter an array of objects on that property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make use of your dynamic property name, try using the property accessor with square brackets like `obj[propertyName] = value`:

```
function dynamicfilter(data, fieldName, filtervalue){
    var filter = {};
    filter[fieldName] = filtervalue;
    $filter('filter')(data, filter);
}
```

As of ES2015, you can also use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). This may not work in all browsers though:

```
 $filter('filter')(data, { [fieldName]: filtervalue });
```

Comment: inside `{ [fieldName]: filtervalue }` having dynamic key like `[fieldName]` will work? I doubt about that

Comment: @PankajParkar this is a new feature `Computed Property Names` of ES2015, I also added a link to mdn for reference, have a look at it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: OMG!! thats nice.. I was thinking in C# way :( +1

Answer (score 0):

Using another syntax will let you do this:

```
var filterData = {}, key = 'myField', value = 'myValue';
filterData[key] = value;
```

Result: `{ myField: 'myValue' }`

Answer (score 0):

you can use somthing like this

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="search1" value="" class = "form-control" id = "search" />

<ng-container *ngFor="let app1 of apps">
      <tr  *ngIf="!search1 || app1.name.includes(search1)">
         <td>{{app1.name}}<td>
          <td>{{app1.login}}<td>  
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
```